# Convert SAS if else to python if else

Tags: python, if-statement, sas

I am converting SAS script to Python and there's a if then else statement that I would like to convert to Python.

Its something like

if mi_proceeds<=1 then mi_coverage =0.01;
else mi_coverage = (mi_proceeds/claim_amt)

if mi_coverage<0.01 then mi_coverage=0.01;
else if mi_coverage>0.01 then mi_coverage=1.00

Comment: Are you asking [how to write](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html) an `if .. : .. elif .. : .. else: ..` statement?

Comment: Are you aware that SO does not teach coding? You can google tutorials for learning python - you can use the python.org one for starters.

Answer (score 0):

Its an odd bit of code, but yeah the answer is very simple.

SAS:
`if mi_proceeds<=1 then mi_coverage =0.01; else mi_coverage = (mi_proceeds/claim_amt)`  
`if mi_coverage<0.01 then mi_coverage=0.01; else if mi_coverage>0.01 then mi_coverage=1.00`

python:

```
if mi_proceeds<=1:  
    mi_coverage =0.01  
else:  
    mi_coverage = (mi_proceeds/claim_amt)  

if mi_coverage<0.01:  
    mi_coverage=0.01  
elif mi_coverage>0.01:  
    mi_coverage=1.00
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not very clear on what you actually want to do, but I suspect you are not asking how to write python if statements, like some commenters seem to, but rather you are probably asking how to write a compiler for this task.

Beware, I am not very well acquainted with SAS. The solution might not be as straightforward as one might think. In a vacuum, it's just a regular language: replace `then` with `:\n\t`, `; else` with `\n else: \n\t`. However, in practice, python's indentation makes the task slightly more difficult. The parsed result will depend on the surrounding indentation.